# A collection with cascade=“all-delete-orphan“ was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance

Tags: spring-boot

call api update it gives error: A collection with cascade=“all-delete-orphan“ was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance when using one to many in jpa. I've been searching and haven't found a solution yet. Do you have a way to help me deal with this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpN1W.png)

code update of me:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTWbS.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.